# Как в числах сделать отступы между разрядами в числах?

Tags: python

У меня есть числа, которые надо привести к строке и сделать оступы по разрядам. Как пример:

```
10000 - "10 000"
1000 - "1 000"
1000000 - "1 000 000"
```

как это можно эффективнее всего сделать?

Answer (score 4):

Делается очень просто:

```
num = 1234567
'{0:,}'.format(num).replace(',', ' ')
```

Comment: Как раз только что откопал похожее решение, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение этой проблемы:

```
import decimal

n = 12782
n = decimal.Decimal(str(n))
n = '{0:,}'.format(n).replace(',', ' ')
```

Comment: зачем лишний раз переводить в Decimal, когда и без этого все работает? Убрать те две строчи и совершенно ничего не изменится. А если так, то они и не нужны, а раз не нужны, то их наличие даже вредно, т.к. ухудшает читаемость кода ничего не улучшая в самом коде.